# Is the acquisition price of a company public information?

Tags: corporate-law, finance

When a company is acquird by another is it possible to hide or not disclose the acquisition price? If it can be hidden, is the company permitted to omit such information on any public financial documents thereafter?

Comment: Are you interested in a particular jurisdiction?